# Providing reverse records for records that map to ISP IP

Tags: networking, routing, isp, reverse-dns

I have been instructed to use my ISP ip (as a temporary fix for mapping my name server and domain records as my router dishes out rfc 1918  adresses to devices in my network  where I am running an Ubuntu server, my router and my development laptop andso I have fixed:

```
$TTL 3H
@ IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
 13112012
 28800
 3600
 604800
 38400
);
thejarbar.org.            IN      A         10.0.0.42
@            IN      NS        ns.thejarbar.org.
yuccalaptop  IN      A          10.0.0.19
ns           IN      A                    10.0.0.42
gw           IN      A                    10.0.0.138
www          IN      CNAME                thejarbar.org.
```

To a temporary version of:

```
$TTL 3H
@ IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
 13112012
 28800
 3600
 604800
 38400
);
thejarbar.org.            IN      A         88.89.190.171
@            IN      NS        ns.thejarbar.org.
yuccalaptop  IN      A          10.0.0.19
ns           IN      A                    88.89.190.171
gw           IN      A                    10.0.0.138
www          IN      CNAME                thejarbar.org.
```

I am using bind and when using `named-checkzone` on this file according to my zone configurations, this file has no errors. I then run `dig thejarbar.org @88.89.190.171` and get an expected authorative reply.

My issue is creating my reverse DNS SOA zone and I would gratly appreciate assistance and guidance. I am stuck on how to represent the reverse records correctly for the eddresses that map to my isp IP. I am trying:

```
$TTL 3H
0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. IN SOA ns.thejarbar.org. email. (
   13112012
   28800
   3600
   604800
   38400
);

171.190.89.88.   IN      PTR     thejarbar.org.
171.190.89.88.       IN      NS      ns.thejarbar.org.

19   IN      PTR     yuccalaptop.thejarbar.org.
138   IN      PTR     gw.thejarbar.org.
www   IN      PTR     www.thejarbar.org.
```

But running named-checkzone on this file leaves an erroneous return that `IN: has no NS records` I would greatly appreciate assistance

Answer (score 1):

You should not be leaking private (rfc 1918) addresses to the Internet.   For you ISP provided IP address, contact your ISP and have them set up a PTR record for you.  It is likely they will only accept one name for the each PRT record.

Most routers route for an entire /24 address block, but only provide DHCP addresses for a portion of the zone.  Other than the routers address, the broadcast (.255) address, and network (.0) address, the rest of the non-DHCP addresses can be used for fixed address devices.  You may want to renumber your devices into this range or configure your route to use your (10.0.0.0/24) address block.

You may find `dnsmasq` simpler to setup than `bind`.  It can read your `/etc/hosts` file and will provide forward and reverse look-ups based on its contents.  Whichever you choose,  configure your router to supply the address of the server running your DNS server.

If you use `bind`, you need to add a zone for `0.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa` to your configuration.   This should be accessible only from within your network.  Something like this should work:

```
zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa." {
     type master;
     file "/etc/bind/db.10_0_0";
     allow-query { local; };
     allow-transfer { local; };
};
```

Recent versions of `bind` can automatically generate empty zoned for private address spaces.  Other configuration have configuration files for empty zones, and you may have to edit it to allow the above zone to work.